# maxLines and inputType="textMultiLine" not working

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

This is my EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:layout_weight="15" />
```

I want it to expand the number of input lines to a max of 4 lines (therefore, maxLines="4"). However, it still shows 1 line (actually 1 and a quarter of the second line is visible).

I tried adding `android:lines="4"` and also `"android:singleLine="false"` but to no avail. How do I get it working?

Here is the complete xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
        android:id="@+id/rlRest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/llInput">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lvMessages"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etMessage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:layout_weight="15"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/bSend"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_send" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentUsers"
    android:name="com.example.abc.OnlineNavDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_online_nav_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_online_nav_drawer" />
```

Comment: Remove layout_weight attribute from your edittext.

Comment: Why is that a problem? I really need that for my layout.

Comment: I suggest you to use a relativelayout instead of linearlayout. Using relativelayout provides you with greater customization of layouts. Also you can improve performance by avoiding nested layouts.

Comment: @Sree14 Did that. Still not working.

Comment: Can you post your full layout?

Comment: @Sree14  added the complete xml.

Comment: the height of the edittext is match_parent. the parent is wrap_content, and the constraining child is the imageview, which has a height of wrap_content. hence, the height of the edittext is the height of the imageview. Use wrap_content in your edittext.

Comment: @njzk2 That worked! Thanks! Add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of the `EditText` is set to `match_parent`.

The parent's height is set to `wrap_content`, and the constraining child is the `ImageView`, which has a height of `wrap_content`.

Hence, the height of the `EditText` is the limited by the height of the `ImageView`.

Use a height of `wrap_content` in your `EditText` to allow it to expand to its full size.